# Firefox update hanging in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I'm using the packaged version of Firefox that came with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation. It's currently v30. Whenever I launch the browser, it tells me an update is available, but I've never been able to update it. When I click the update button, the dialog says `Connecting to the update server...` with an indeterminate progress bar, and stays like that indefinitely.

Is there anything I can do to diagnose this issue or does anyone know of any fix?

Comment: It sounds like you are runing firefox with sudo.

Comment: I always launch it from a terminal with `firefox &`

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and type the following commands -

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade firefox`

This will upgrade Firefox to the latest version, ie 34.

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version.
firefox set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: Damn, I must be launching some other stale version of Firefox whenever I run `firefox &` from a terminal to launch it...

Comment: It still says it's the already the newest version after the `--only-upgrade`, but if I run `firefox -version` I get `Mozilla Firefox 30.0`